# What's preferred pattern for reading lines from a file in C++?

Tags: c++, file-io

I've seen at least two ways of reading lines from a file in C++ tutorials:

```
std::ifstream fs("myfile.txt");
if (fs.is_open()) {
  while (fs.good()) {
    std::string line;
    std::getline(fs, line);
    // ...
```

and:

```
std::ifstream fs("myfile.txt");
std::string line;
while (std::getline(fs, line)) {
  // ...
```

Of course, I can add a few checks to make sure that the file exists and is opened. Other than the exception handling, is there a reason to prefer the more-verbose first pattern? What's your standard practice?

Comment: It's not *quite* an exact duplicate, but the answers to a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567082/how-do-i-iterate-over-cin-line-by-line-in-c/1567703) are relevant.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
while (std::getline(fs, line))
{}
```

This is not only correct but *preferable also* **because it is idiomatic.**

I assume in the first case, you're not checking `fs` after `std::getline()` as `if(!fs) break;` or something equivalent. Because if you don't do so, then the first case is completely wrong. Or if you do that, then second one is still preferable as its more concise and clear in logic.

The function `good()` should be used *after* you made an attempt to read from the stream; its used to check if the attempt was successful. In your first case, you don't do so. After `std::getline()`, you assume that the read was successful, without even checking what `fs.good()` returns. Also, you seem to assume that if `fs.good()` returns true, `std::getline` would successfully read a line from the stream. You're going exactly in the opposite direction: the fact is that, if `std::getline` successfully reads a line from the stream, then `fs.good()` would return `true`.

The documentation at cplusplus says about [`good()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good) that,

> The function returns true if none of the stream's error flags (eofbit, failbit and badbit) are set.

That is, when you attempt to read data from an input stream, and if the attempt was failure, only then a failure flag is set and `good()` returns `false` as an indication of the failure.

If you want to limit the scope of `line` variable to inside the loop only, then you can write a `for` loop as:

```
for(std::string line; std::getline(fs, line); )
{
   //use 'line'
}
```

Note: this solution came to my mind after reading @john's solution, but I think its better than his version.

---

Read a detail explanation here why the second one is preferable and idiomatic:

- [Linux | Segmentation Fault in C++ - Due to the function ifstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931535/linux-segmentation-fault-in-c-due-to-the-function-ifstream/6931564#6931564)

Or read this nicely written blog by @Jerry Coffin:

- [Reading files](http://coderscentral.blogspot.com/2011/03/reading-files.html)

Comment: yikes, the top google hit for me was http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ How in the world did the method name good() make it into the standard? :)

Comment: @jda: The function `good()` should be used *after* you made an attempt to read from the stream; its used to check if the attempt was successful. In your first case, you don't do so. After `std::getline()`, you assume that the read was successful, without even checking what `fs.good()` returns. Also, you seem to assume that if `fs.good()` returns true, `std::getline` would successfully read a line from the stream. You're going exactly in the opposite direction: the fact is that, if `std::getline` successfully reads a line from the stream, then `fs.good()` would return `true`.

Comment: @jda: I added some more explanation to my answer. Please read it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was pretty much copying the cplusplus.com example, which seems to do this incorrectly, as you point out.

Comment: @Nawaz: An alternative that limits scope and that still retains use of the standard idiom is to put the declaration and the loop into a block: `{ std::line line; while (getline(fs, line)) {...} }`. Not that I would use this; I just use the standard idiom. BTW, very nice post.

Comment: The function `good()` should _never_ be used.  If the preceding input succeeded, it may or may not return `true`; you don't know and cannot count on it.  If the preceding input failed, it will return `false`, so there's no point in calling it.

Comment: What if the last line of the file is not NL-terminated?

Comment: @lav: Not an issue. Please try it.

Comment: @Nawaz: Correct. std::getline only sets badbit if it could read no characters at all. It sets eofbit if the line is not NL-terminated, but it that case istream's operator bool still returns true, so the line is processed correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Think of this as an extended comment to Nawaz' already excellent answer.

Regarding your first option,

```
while (fs.good()) {
  std::string line;
  std::getline(fs, line);
  ...
```

This has multiple problems. Problem number 1 as that that the `while` condition is in the wrong place and is superfluous. It's in the wrong place because `fs.good()` indicates whether or not the most recent action performed on the file was OK. A while condition should be with respect to the upcoming actions, not the previous ones. There is no way to know whether the upcoming action on the file will be OK. What upcoming action? `fs.good()` does not read your code to see what that upcoming action is.

Problem number two is that the you are ignoring the return status from `std::getline()`. That's OK if you immediately check the status with `fs.good()`. So, fixing this up a bit,

```
while (true) {
  std::string line;
  if (std::getline(fs, line)) {
    ...
  }
  else {
     break;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can do `if (! std::getline(fs, line)) { break; }` but now you have a `break` in the middle of the loop. Yech. It is much, much better to make the exit conditions a part of the loop statement itself if at all possible.

Compare that to

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(fs, line)) {
  ...
}
```

This is *the* standard idiom for reading lines from a file. A very similar idiom exists in C. This idiom is very old, very widely used, and very widely viewed as *the* correct way to read lines from a file.

What if you come from a shop that bans conditionals with side-effects? (There are lots and lots of programming standards that do just that.) There is a way around this without resorting to the break in the middle of the loop approach:

```
std::string line;
for (std::getline(fs, line); fs.good(); std::getline(fs, line)) {
  ...
}
```

Not as ugly as the break approach, but most will agree that this isn't nearly as nice-looking as is the standard idiom.

My recommendation is to use the standard idiom unless some standards idiot has banned its use.

**Addendum**
Regarding `for (std::getline(fs, line); fs.good(); std::getline(fs, line))`: This is ugly for two reasons. One is that obvious chunk of replicated code.

Less obvious is that calling `getline` and then `good` breaks atomicity. What if some other thread is also reading from the file? This isn't quite so important right now because C++ I/O currently is not threadsafe. It will be in the upcoming C++11. Breaking atomicity just to keep the enforcers of the standards happy is recipe for disaster.

Comment: If anyone thinks your final example is better than your penultimate one, they really are a 'standards idiot'. Code repetition is bad.

Comment: @john: There are, unfortunately, plenty of people who do think my final example is preferable. The small amount of replicated code doesn't bother me near so much as does the loss of atomicity. The same concept applies to function that is *supposed to* perform a complex transaction in a mulithreaded environment (but sometimes the transaction fails). There are plenty of places where programming with side-effects is not only acceptable but is the only way to go.

Comment: The idium was Inhereted from older languages and is practically universal

Comment: @Martin: I said that: "A very similar idiom exists in C. This idiom is very old, very widely used, and very widely viewed as *the* correct way to read lines from a file."

Answer (score 2):

Actually I prefer another way

```
for (;;)
{
  std::string line;
  if (!getline(myFile, line))
    break;
  ...
}
```

To me it reads better, and the string is scoped correctly (i.e. inside the loop where it is being used, not outside the loop)

But of the two you've written the second is correct.

Comment: To me, an infinite loop with a break in the middle is on the border of being an anti-pattern.

Comment: If you care for scope of the string variable, then why don't you simply write `for(string line; getline(fs,line); ) {}`?

Comment: @David Hammen: Break at the top I think you'll find. The scoping issue is the real gain. But there you go, style issues, people never agree.

Comment: @Nawaz: I think because when I started programming C++ that wasn't possible. But good point.

Comment: @David Hammen, I used to program Pascal, Pascal doesn't have a break and you were for ever seeing this kind of loop `code; while (condition) { ...; code; }` Now that is an anti-pattern because of the repetition of `code`. Now you can clean that up with `while (function(...)) { ... }` where function incorporates both `code;` and `condition` or you can do it my way `for (;;) { code; if (!condition) break; ... }`. To me both are reasonable depending on which produces the cleaner result, which is of course subjective.

Comment: @john: If your driving concern is scoping, you can still use the standard idiom via `{std::string line; while (std::getline(fs, line)) {...}}`. A driving reason to use *the* standard idiom is that any reasonably intelligent programmer who reads your code (say for a code review) will immediately understand what you are doing. Do something different and the programmer will wonder why you are doing this and will also question your programming savvy -- and usually for good reason.

Comment: @Cheers David! I love you to.

Comment: Another problem with this is that the string gets allocated/dealocated each time round the loop.I'm with `for(std::string line; std::getline(is, line);){}`

Answer (score 1):

The first one deallocated and re-allocated the string every loop, wasting time.
The second time writes the string to an already existing space removing the deallocation and reallocation, making it actually faster (and better) than the first one.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not so concerned about that though. I could always move the declaration outside the loop, but I'm told (I could be wrong about this) that C++ compilers are smart about allocation and the best practice is to move the declaration as close to the usage as possible.

Comment: @jda, i'm not sure that compiler would be smart enough to optimise the allocation (I could be wrong) but your second point is what matters. Don't micro-optimise unless you've a demonstrated need too, write clean code first.

Comment: An even halfway decent optimizing compiler will get rid of that repeated allocation and deallocation. This just isn't a concern unless you are compiling with optimization off. When you compile C++ with optimization off you will have lots and lots of performance concerns, this being just a tiny part of those concerns.

Comment: @David Hammen: actually no. Using LLVM compiler I tested the the compiler assembly outputs with `-O3` optimization and saw that `new` is being called in a loop when the string in the loop and called only one when the string is out of it. for reference the code is http://pastebin.com/6ErddNSS

Answer (score -5):

Try this =>

```
// reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {
      getline (myfile,line);
      cout << line << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let me guess. You went and copied this over from cplusplus.com. That site has lots of mistakes in it, including this one.