# Reading and comparing lines from a text-file

Tags: c++

I have this code that I want to read lines from a text-file and find unique codes from that line. Here is a little of what my text-file reads:

> AGU UAC AUU GCG CGA UGG GCC UCG AGA CCC GGG UUU AAA GUA GGU GA
>
> > GUU ACA UUG CGC GAU GGG CCU CGA GAC CCG GGU UUA AAG UAG GUG A
>
> UUA CAU UGC GCG  M  GGC CUC GAG ACC CGG GUU UAA AGU AGG UGA
>
> UGG  M  AAA UUU GGG CCC AGA GCU CCG GGU AGC GCG UUA CAU UGA

I want to find the lines that contain the letter `'M'` and make them separate strings so that I can break them up even more and compare them. I am having a little trouble though.
I am trying to find them and the assign it to a string, but it seems to assign all the lines to the same string. This is what I have so far:

```
ifstream code_File ("example.txt");   // open text file.
if (code_File.is_open()) {
   while (code_File.good()) {
      getline(code_File,line);    //get the contents of file 
      cout  << line << endl;     // output contents of file on screen.
      found = line.find_first_of('M', 0);               // Finding start code
      if (found != string::npos) {
         code_Assign.assign(line, int(found), 100);        
         /* assign the line to code_Assign and print out string from where I 
            found the start code 'M'. */
         cout << endl << "code_Assign: " << code_Assign << endl << endl;
```

ED: Should I use string replace instead of assign?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve when assigning to ``code_Assign``? The problem I see so far is that ``assign`` will overwrite whatever ``code_Assign`` had each time. If you're trying to collect all the lines you want to use a vector of strings.

Comment: So when I find the very first 'M' in my text file, I want to assign that whole line (and just that line) as a string to Code_Assign and print it out. And that is what I want to do every time I see an 'M' after that too, but they all need to be different strings. How do you use Vector of strings? I have not learned vectors...yet.

Comment: I don't see any obvious bug then. Note though that you're not assigning the whole line to code_Assign, you're just assigning the 100 characters after the position of M.

Comment: You need a vector of strings, suggest you start learning about them.

Comment: You should also fix your while loop `while (code_file.good()) { getline(code_File,line) ... }` is wrong. Just because your file is good doesn't mean that you can read a line from it. Correct loop is `while (getline(code_file,line) { ... }`. This loop tests if you succesfully read a line from the file, which is what you want.

Comment: is this your whole code?

Comment: In order for us to help you we need to understand your problem better. The best way to help us do that is by posting an [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You rewrite `code_Assign` every iteration. `code_Assign.assign(line, int(found), 100);` assign the string with a *new* content from `line` and the previous content is lost. Using replace won't do either. You need to store strings somewhere and the easiest way is to use a `vector`.

You declare an empty vector of strings like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> my_vector_of_strings;
```

Unlike an ordinary array, vector dynamically resizes itself when you add elements to it so you don't need to know how big it needs to be at compile time. More info here: [vector reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Next,

```
   while (code_File.good()) {
        getline(code_File,line);
```

is bad form and it's been explained many times before on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7219066/947836), for example).
Move the `getline()` call in `while` condition. Your code should look something like this:

```
// untested

ifstream code_File ("example.txt");   // open text file.
vector<string> vec_str;               // declare an empty vector of strings
string line;

if (code_File.is_open())
    while (getline(code_File, line)) { // read a line and only enter the loop if it succeeds 
        size_t found = line.find_first_of('M');  // you can omit the second parameter, it defaults to 0 
        if (found != string::npos) {
             line = line.substr(found); // take a substring from where we found 'M' to the end 
             vec_str.push_back(line);   // add the line to the vector
        }
    }

// print out the lines in vector:

for (size_t i = 0; i < vec_str.size(); i++)
    cout << vec_str[i] << endl;

// or, prettier, using the new c++11's range based for:

for (string s& : vec_str) cout << s << endl;
```

Hope that helps.