# STL containers & memory leaks

Tags: c++, stl

C# coder just wrote this simple C++ method to get text from a file:

```
static std::vector<std::string> readTextFile(const std::string &filePath) {
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    std::ifstream theFile(filePath.c_str());
    while (theFile.good()) {
    getline (theFile, line);
        lines.push_back(line);
    }
    theFile.close();
    return lines;
}
```

I know this code is not efficient; the text lines are copied once as they are read and a second time when returned-by-value.

Two questions:

(1) can this code leak memory ?
(2) more generally can returning containers of objects by value ever leak memory ?  (assuming the objects themselves don't leak)

Comment: You probably don't want `static` everywhere like you do in C#. Also, containers take care of freeing memory when they are destroyed, which, when allocated on the stack like you have, is when they go out of scope.

Comment: Actually return-by-value doesn't necessarily leads to a copy. It can possibly be avoided due to [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NRVO) or, if c++11 is used and RVO is impossible the return value is moved instead of beeing copied (moving a `vector` costs about three pointer assignments, so that doesn't really cost much). And no, returning objects by value doesn't leak memory if the object itself is correct. In c++ you are generally fine with regards to leaking memory unless you start using `new`

Comment: Better: `while (std::getline(theFile, line))`, otherwise you get an extra empty line at eof. Apart from that, the code is fine. In C++11 you have idiomatic ways to avoid the extra copies. In C++03, you often prefer the extra copies to convolved code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while (theFile.good()) {
 getline (theFile, line);
    lines.push_back(line);
}
```

Forget about efficiency, this code is not correct. It will not read the file correctly. See the following topic to know ***why***:

- [What's preferred pattern for reading lines from a file in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219062/whats-preferred-pattern-for-reading-lines-from-a-file-in-c)

So the loop should be written as:

```
while (getline (theFile, line)) {
    lines.push_back(line);
}
```

Now this is correct. If you want to make it efficient, profile your application first. Try see the part which takes most CPU cycles.

---

> (1) can this code leak memory ?

No.

> (2) more generally can returning containers of objects by value ever leak memory ?

Depends on the *type* of the object in the containers. In your case, the *type* of the object in `std::vector` is `std::string` which makes sure that no memory will be leaked.

Answer (score 1):

No and no. Returning by value never leaks memory (assuming the containers and the contained objects are well written). It would be fairly useless if it was any other way.

And I second what Nawaz says, your while loop is wrong. It's frankly incredible how many times we see that, there must be an awful lot of bad advice out there.

Comment: thanks - fyi I got the loop construct at "www.cplusplus.com".  I guess even with a name like that one has to be careful about clipping snippets.

Comment: @tpascale Would be interested to know the exact address.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ and see the 2nd example in the section "Text Files".

Comment: Interesting, the text is actually OK, it implies that good() is false *after* the last I/O operation fails. But if the author knew that why did they write the loop that way?

Answer (score 1):

> (1) can this code leak memory ?

No

> (2) more generally can returning containers of objects by value ever leak memory ?

No. You might leak memory that is stored in a container by pointer or through objects that leak. But that would not be caused by *returning by value*.

> I know this code is not efficient; the text lines are copied once as they are read and a second time when returned-by-value.

Most probably not. There are two copies of the string, but not the ones that you are thinking about. The return copy will most likely be optimized in C++03, and will either be optimized away or transformed into a move (cheap) in C++11.

The two copes are rather:

```
getline (theFile, line);
lines.push_back(line);
```

The first line copies from the file to `line`, and the second copies from `line` to the container. If you are using a C++11 compiler you can change the second line to:

```
lines.push_back(std::move(line));
```

to *move* the contents of the string to the container. Alternatively (and also valid in C++03), you can change the two lines with:

```
lines.push_back(std::string()); // In most implementations this is *cheap*
                                // (i.e. no memory allocation)
getline(theFile, lines.back());
```

And you should test the result of the read (if the read fails, in the last alternative, make sure to `resize` to one less element to remove the last empty string.

Comment: To remove the last element, you can use `pop_back`. That's way simpler than getting the length, subtracting 1 and `resize`ing.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, you can do:

```
std::vector<std::string> 
read_text_file(const std::string& path) 
{
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> ans;
    std::ifstream file(path.c_str());

    while (std::getline(file, line))
       ans.push_back(std::move(line));

    return ans;
}
```

and no extra copies are made.

In C++03, you accept the extra copies, and painfully remove them only if profiling dictates so.

Note: you don't need to close the file manually, the destructor of `std::ifstream` does it for you.

Note2: You can template on the char type, this may be useful in some circumstances:

```
template <typename C, typename T>
std::vector<std::basic_string<C, T>>
read_text_file(const char* path)
{
    std::basic_string<C, T> line;
    std::vector<std::basic_string<C, T>> ans;
    std::basic_ifstream<C, T> file(path);

    // Rest as above
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, returning container by value should not leak memory. The standard library is designed not to leak memory itself in any case. It can only leak a memory if there is a bug in its implementation. At least there used to be a [bug in vector of strings](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/596565/memory-leak-with-std-vector-std-string-insert-using-const-std-string#details) in an old MSVC.