# trying to read a config file

Tags: c++

sorry in advance for the formatting. Couldn't figure it out...

I'm passing a config file to a program via arguments

I'm trying to read a value from a specific parameter

I've got a cofigReader class with the following method for returning a string from a config file given a specific parameter

My problem,

it never finds the parameter. found is either 0 or -1....

```
string configReader::value(string config_file, string parameter)
{
    string value;
    char config_delimiter = '=';
    size_t found;
    file.open(config_file);
    std::string line;
    bool param_found = false;
    while(param_found == false){
        while (!file.eof())
        {       
            getline(file,line);
            logger.writetolog("INFO","Looking for " + parameter +
                         " on line "+ line); 
            found = line.find(parameter);
            logger.writetolog("INFO",int(found));
            if(found!=string::npos){
                param_found = true;
            }
        }
        param_found = true;
    }
    if (found!=string::npos)
    {   
        size_t a = line.find(config_delimiter)+1;
        logger.writetolog("INFO","Found" + parameter + 
                   "splitting string at delimter" + config_delimiter + 
                   " and return right side value");     
        value = line.substr(a);
        return value;
    }
    else
    {
        return value;
    }
    file.close();
}
```

more info. Config file reads like this.

```
toemail=someemailaddress@gmail.com
outputdir=C:\tmp
```

configReader class used like this

```
//attempt to parse out the required parameters for the program
string toemail = config.value(configFileArg,"toemail");
```

it ALWAYS return empty

Comment: If `found` is `0` then the parameter _was_ found at the start of the string.  What does the output look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `while (!file.eof())` loop continues after you find a match, over-writing the value of `found` which you check later.

You could fix this by changing your loop to something like

```
bool param_found = false;
while (!param_found && !file.eof()) {       
    if (getline(file,line)) {
        break;
    }
    logger.writetolog("INFO","Looking for " + parameter +" on line "+ line); 
    found = line.find(parameter);
    logger.writetolog("INFO",int(found));
    if(found!=string::npos){
        param_found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

instead.  (Notice that this code removes your while(param_found == false) loop.  As sftrabbit points out, that loop is unnecessary.)

Comment: Also, the outer `while` loop is pointless. It only ever loops once.

Comment: Yep, thanks, +1.  I'd noticed that but you just beat me to it with your post :)

Comment: What if `getline(file,line);` fails? The loop should be written as `while (getline(file,line))` and you can break it anytime, setting whatever variables to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, your code works. Learning is difficult, but easier with stack.

Comment: @Nawaz Do you mean the lack of test for `getline` failure?  I'd omitted that rather than copy your answer.  In hindsight, an accepted answer that isn't quite right isn't ideal so I've updated my answer with an alternative attempt at error handling.  If the loop is still wrong can you be more specific about the other problems please?

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic way to write loop is this:

```
bool param_found = false;

while (std::getline(file,line)) //<-- this is idiomatic loop!
{                               //successfully read OR exit from the loop

    logger.writetolog("INFO","Looking for " + parameter +" on line "+ line); 
    found = line.find(parameter);
    logger.writetolog("INFO",int(found));
    if(found!=string::npos){
        param_found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

You should not use `eof()` when writing loops:

- [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)
- [What's preferred pattern for reading lines from a file in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219062/whats-preferred-pattern-for-reading-lines-from-a-file-in-c)

These two topics discuss this in detail.

Comment: interesting. very interesting. So, no EOF needeD?

Comment: @nkuebelbeck: Yes, `eof()` is useless for such loops.

Comment: I was always told that reading files required it. +1 for the internet and -1 for academia.