# C++: Read .txt contents and store into 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, filestream

So me and my groupmates suddenly have some clutchwork at hand. I was assigned of making an import function that reads through a textfile that looks like this, and store it to a 2D array:
[image]

The columns are Tab-separated. As this suddenly came up, dont have the entire project file with me and I am nowhere near my old reliables, I tried conjuring this up in the most generic way possible:

```
void signal::import_data(string filename){
    ifstream file;

    file.open(filename.c_str());

    if(file.fail()){
        cerr << "file open fail" << endl;
    }else{
        while(!file.eof)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < NumCols; j++){
                for(int i = 0; i < NumRows; i++){
                    file >> _data[j][i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Am I doing this correct? Im not so sure if streaming like this can bypass tabs, or can it?

Comment: Avoid this : `while(!file.eof)`,and read as `if ( !(file >> _data[j][i])) break;`

Comment: Understood! But is the rest of the code alright? Also, honestly? I dont really know why while(!file.eof) is a viable option, just wondering if you can tell me why

Comment: @Erasmus: I believe you should avoid `while (!file.eof())` because if the token read from the input stream when doing `file >> ...` cannot be parsed into an integer, then the input iterator will not advance. If that's the case, you may never reach the end of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this code:

```
while(!file.eof)
{
   for(int j = 0; j < NumCols; j++){
       for(int i = 0; i < NumRows; i++){
              file >> _data[j][i];
      }
   }
}
```

should be replaced with this:

```
for(int j = 0; j < NumCols; j++)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < NumRows; i++)
   {
         if ( !(file >> _data[j][i]) ) 
         {
             std::cerr << "error while reading file";
             break;
         }
   }
   if ( !file ) break;
}
```

That is, if you expect `NumCols * NumRows` entries to be there in the file, why explicitly check for end of file? Let it read till you read `NumCols * NumRows` entries is read. Once it read, it will automatically exit from the loop.

But you must check if the file ends *before* `NumCols * NumRows` entries is read, which is why I'm doing this:

```
if ( !(file >> _data[j][i]) ) 
{
    std::cerr << "error while reading file";
    break;
}
```

If the file reaches *eof* character, OR some other read-failure before it finishes reading `NumCols * NumRows` entries, then the condition in the `if` would evaluate to `true` and it will print the error message and break the loop, it will break outer loop also, as the expression `!file` will evaluate to `true`.

For a detail explanation as to HOW TO read files using C++ streams, read the answers from these topics:

- [What's preferred pattern for reading lines from a file in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219062/whats-preferred-pattern-for-reading-lines-from-a-file-in-c)
- [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)