# read last line in c++

Tags: c++, ifstream

for some reason, my program doesn't print the last line of a textfile if the last line contains less characters than the buffer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream read("test.txt");
    char buffer[12];

    while(!read.eof())
    {
        read.getline(buffer,11);
        if(!read.eof())
            std::cout<<buffer<<'\n';
        read.clear();

    }
    read.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's preferred pattern for reading lines from a file in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219062/whats-preferred-pattern-for-reading-lines-from-a-file-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing the line out under condition that `if(!read.eof())`, but that condition will evaluate to false after the last line was read with `getline()`.

Comment: thx, when i deleted the if-test, the program didn't work because i did a clear first and then checked in the while if it reached the end of file. So i had to put the clear before the getline in the while loop. Now the program works fine :)

Comment: It may or may not evaluate to false after the last line was read.  The fact that the results may be inconsistent is the main reason _why_ we never test `eof()` until we know that the input has failed.